# How to make a custom redux-form component control multiple fields?

Tags: redux-form

I want to have a `Map` with a draggable marker that determines both `x` and `y` fields.

```
<Fields names={['x', 'y']} component={Map} />
```

When the marker is dropped to a new location on the map, how do I tell redux-form what the new `x` and `y` values are?

http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/faq/CustomComponent.md/

Comment: As per http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Field.md/, component can be Component|Function|String [required]. Still not clear what you meant by single`Map` component.

Comment: Thanks @SherinMathew I've edited the question for clarity

Comment: `this.props.onChange({ x, y })` ? Can you not just store an object as the value?

Comment: Don't think so—it's hooked up to an existing API that has the flat values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const renderMap = props => (
  <DragDrop
    image={props.image}
    currentValue={{
      x: props.x.input.value,
      y: props.y.input.value,
    }}
    thingsChanged={coords => {
      props.x.input.onChange(coords.x);
      props.y.input.onChange(coords.y);
    }} />
)

<Fields
  names={['x', 'y']}
  component={renderMap}
  image={this.state.image} />
```